# Firefox PDF Embedded Plugin

Tags: firefox, plugins

For some reason in firefox i cannot read embedded pdfs.  it just says a plugin is needed to display the content and then has a link to download plugin.  when i click it, it searches for a while and then says no suitable plugins were found.  I tried the same thing in chrome and it read it automatically.  I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: See firefoxs-built-in-pdf-viewer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/258535/how-can-i-use-firefoxs-built-in-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**mozplugger**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mozplugger/) will allow you to open PDF as well as other things....

From Ubuntu's software Centers onlinne page(linked to above)

> mozplugger allows you to seamlessly integrate external applications to view files downloaded from the web that Mozilla can not normally handle. The application is embedded within a Mozilla window as to act like and feel like a true plugin.
>
> This allows you to view PDFs, Postscript files, animations and movies, amongst other file types all from within Mozilla (with supporting applications).

You can install it with the link provided or search for it in the software center directly...

One note however, this program doesn't always work seamlessly, it is supposed to open the PDF file ***inside*** the browser but sometimes it will open it in the `document veiwer` outside the web browser, but at least it still opens the page.  I have not had any problems with videos opening in a browser window, just PDF files for some reason, I have not been able to figure out exactly what circumstances cause this problem do I;m not sure if there is a bug report on it, it works well enough so I'm not that worried about it....

Comment: thanks, i saw a post with this but only saw them talking about using it externally or something.  but it works for me! thanks

Comment: glad I could help, this drove me nuts as well when I first started using Ubuntu(11.04), not sure how I stumbled across this fix but I was thrilled to find it