# How can I use Firefox's built in PDF viewer?

Tags: firefox, pdf

I downloaded firefox 19 and executed it on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I went to a website with pdf links, clicked on one of them, hoping to have it shown in the built-in pdf viewer in Firefox 19, but only got the common pop-up menu with the options of viewing it with Evince or downloading it to a folder. How can I use Firefox 19 built-in pdf viewer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to *Edit → Preferences → Applications* and select *Preview in Firefox* for the content-type *Portable Document Format (PDF)*.

[image: Aurora Preferences]

Also, to confirm whether pdf.js (the inbuilt pdf viewer) is enabled, type `about:config` in the browser's address bar, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, accept the warning, and, in the next screen, enter `pdfjs` in the search bar; you should see an entry with *pdfjs.disabled* in the *Preference Name* column. If its value is *true*, highlight that line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle and set the value to *false*.

Comment: `Preview in Aurora` doesn't show as an option. Maybe I need to clean up my older Firefox configuration?

Comment: Did you check the value of *pdjs.disabled*?

Comment: @213441265152351: Sorry, it should be preview in firefox for you.

Comment: I think enabling _pdfjs_ is enough, as I did for its first release.